# Can't POST data to Shopify using Proxy

Tags: shopify

I'm attempting to POST data to a shopify store via a proxy page. I have been able to GET data via the URL on a proxy page but I have been getting the same error over and over again when attempting to POST data.

The error is:

```
{
    "errors": {
        "fulfillment": "Required parameter missing or invalid"
    }
}
```

However the API states that I can POST data to a URL like the one below (I've masked the URL a bit to protect security Info) http://docs.shopify.com/api/fulfillment#create

```
https://XXXXXXX:XXXXXXX@XXXXXXX.myshopify.com/admin/orders/238974545/fulfillments.json
```

The data that I am attempting to post is:

> {
>   "fulfillment":{"tracking_number":"9405510200881104822769","notify_customer":
>   false}}

Has anyone experienced this? If so how have you overcome this?

Comment: I am also getting same error while creating webhooks using API

Comment: How did you resolve this? I'm having the same problem.

Answer (score 2):

I was getting this same error. Here: https://ecommerce.shopify.com/c/shopify-apis-and-technology/t/fulfill-by-api-190660#comment-190683 shopify support recommended that you specify the header Content-type as application/json in your http request. I did this and it fixed the problem.